# Cant deploy Fiori App to System using SAP Business Application Studio

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have developed my first fiori app using sap bas and am trying to deploy it to our test-system.
The test-system is connected to sap bas via SCC/OData and receiving data via the odata services is working fine.
To deploy the app i run these commands:

1. npm install
2. npm run build
3. abap-deploy --log-level=error

After running the last command, it says "deploying..." and then throws this "error" message:
[image]

sadly nothing is written to the error log file :(
When trying to run the service in my system, it opens the webpage that simply says "Error: File NOT found!

am thankful for any ideas on how to fix this :)

Comment: Have you activated the relevant SICF nodes?

Comment: thanks for your answer, the relevant nodes were activated. I now used /UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD to deploy my program

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the abap-deploy command in SAP BAS is deprecated!
I used program /UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD to deploy my app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: BAS is just calling your npm modules. Update your modules e.g. I think this is the official tooling https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sap/ux-ui5-tooling. There are a few deploy tasks. Even better would be to use a ci pipeline. Hand deployment is never a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

1 - First we create a configuration file through the command:

**npx fiori add deploy-config**

2 - Then we deploy it using the command:

**npm run deploy**